# want to get value from html to php

Tags: php, html

My current php code is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
$font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
$text = $_GET['name'] ;
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

It is perfectly working I'm using `$_GET['name']` to get text input from the user from input tag in html which name is `name="name"`  and now I'm trying to get value from the combo box

my html code for combo box:

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control input-lg" maxlength="12">

>
<option value="male">male</option>
<option value="female">female</option>

</select>
```

when I'm trying to get value from the `$_GET['gender'];` the value which is selected by the user is not shown on the image. Help me out!

I have tried this also

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
$font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
$text = $_GET['name'] ;
$text2= $_GET['gender'];
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 80, 60, $white, $font_path, $text2);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

but not working

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, you are using form tags, right?

Comment: @learner , why an extra `>` is within your `select`?

Comment: ^ I was going to mention that ^ remove it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: the select element, is it already inside form method get?

Comment: I'm not using form method without form method I'm getting value from `$_GET['name']` but when I'm using `$_GET['gender']` I'm not getting any value

Comment: Does the `name` gets printed in the image and the `gender` not, or neither of the two are being printed?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$text = $_GET['name'] ;`, however the select has `name="gender"`. You need to either change the name of the select to `name`, or access it's value via `$_GET['gender']`

Comment: The last codding is the example which i have tried  and only getting text from the input tag of html which name is name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75654/discussion-between-learner-and-cristik).